# How can I refactor this to avoid InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach, casting

Basically here i'm looking create a list of "PaymentPayloads" (custom type) by looking for queueItems with a valid itemId and then casting it to a PaymentPayload item and adding each to the list. However with this Cast error, is another solution possible?

```
    var paymentPayloads = new List<PaymentPayload>();

    try
    {
         paymentPayloads = queueItems.Where(x => queueItemIds.Any(y => y == x.ItemId))
                             .Select(x => (PaymentPayload)x.Payload)
                             .ToList();
    }
    catch
    {
         throw new InvalidCastException();
    }
```

The QueueItem class has a field "Payload" of type "PayloadBase"

```
    public PayloadBase Payload { get; set; }
```

My PaymentPayload class inherits PayloadBase like so

```
    public class PaymentPayload : PayloadBase
```

Can anyone tell me why this cast is invalid and any valid alternatives I can do instead? Maybe creating a new object in some kind of a foreach loop?

Comment: You can't cast an instance of a base type to one of its derived types. If `PaymentPayload` had fields which weren't inherited from `PayloadBase`, and you were able to cast a `PayloadBase` to a `PaymentPayload`, what values would these fields have?

Comment: while "upcasts" are allright (abstraction), whenever you have Downcasts, you should pay attention if you got a design problen ("forbidden knowledge").

Comment: Blank or default values i think.

Comment: Should I create a new PaymentPayload for each instead of casting then?

Comment: that won't change much. Of course it avoids the exception. However it does not change if or if not getting from a base-object to a derived one makes sense. This is a point only you can handle appropriately, as we don't know why the objects are of the base-type in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me why this cast is invalid and any valid alternatives I can do instead?

The cast is invalid because at least some items have a payload that is not of type `PaymentPayload`. It might be of `PayloadBase` if it is not abstract, or some other derived type. Your debugger and or IDE should be able to tell you what the type actually is and what types derive from `PayloadBase`.

If you only want to process items where the payload is a `PaymentPayload` you can use

```
.Select(x => x.Payload)
.OfType<PaymentPayload>()
```

But there is no way to tell if this will give the correct behavior.

Are *all* payloads intended to be `PaymentPayload`? If so the type of the property should be changed.

Are all payloads intended to be of the *same* type, all derived from `PayloadBase` ? Then using generics with a constraint might be appropriate.

Is Payloads intended to be of multiple mixed types? Then you need to know how each type should be handled, simply ignoring all other types than `PaymentPayload` *might* be the correct behavior, but only you and your colleagues understand the details of your application and how it is intended to work.

When you downcast objects, i.e. cast PayloadBase to PaymentPayload, and not the reverse, you intentionally ignore the protections the type system gives you. In essence telling the compiler that you know more than it does. But that moves the responsibility for ensuring the types match to *you*. So in well designed code direct casts tend to be fairly rare, a more typical approach is to use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/csharp-8-0-pattern-matching-in-csharp-8-0).

Comment: 'Unable to cast object of type 'PayloadBase' to type 'PaymentPayload'.'

Yes there is only one item. Within PayloadBase there is only one field and I want to be able to write this field from within the PayloadBase to a new PaymentPayload

Comment: @juicejuiceeire then it sounds like you want something like `.Select(x => new PaymentPayload(x.Payload.MyProperty))`. But your question is not very clear. Providing a minimal reproducible example of what you want would probably be useful.